# Ajax - how to pass get value from form to Controller?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, get

I have the following form:

```
<form>
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <button>Join</button>
</form>
```

And I want to pass get value to my controller which has route to `/add/{email}`

Controller Code:

```
public function addToNewsletterAction(Request $request){
    //Some actions
}
```

How do I pass get value?
Current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#newsletterButton").on("click", function() {
        var email = $('.email').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: "/add/newsletter/{email}",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            succes: function() {
                alert("Done");
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: show your ajax.

Comment: I've updated in question just now

Comment: Why putting email as part of the route, just post it like other fields. Moreover your route shouldn't be hard-coded, if your are in dev env you will loose your current environment context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to change that so you can send a variable because here you send `"/add/newsletter/{email}"` wich is not what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#newsletterButton").on("click",function () {
        var email = $('.email').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url: "/add/newsletter/".email,
            data:$("form").serialize(),
            succes: function () {
                alert("Done");
            }
        })
     })
})
```

then in your controller :

```
public function addToNewsletterAction($email){
   //do something with the email var
}
```

But you should try to just send things like id by your url so change your route with that : `/add/newsletter`

then in your controller you cand do :

```
public function addToNewsletterAction(Request $request){
    $email = $request->request->get('email');
    $other = $request->request->get('other')
 }
```

and dont forget to change in your .twig : `url:"/add/newsletter"`

And you have a problem in your code. Your button doesn't have an id, wich I supposed should be `newsletterButton` here

**Edit**
to get the email you can use getElementById and add an onClick function in your button. Change your form by something like that :

```
<form>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Join</button>
</form>
```

then in your script you add the myFunction :

```
function myFunction() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url: "/add/newsletter/",
        data: {
            'email' : email,
        }
        succes: function () {
            alert("Done");
        }
    })
 })
```

})

Comment: I have code with Json response and if I pass argument like /add/newsletter/admin@local.com it works fine. But I stuck on get value from form.

Comment: @Chrzanek i just changed it ;)

Comment: i like your approach but please don't send data via route AND get-parameter. the JS isn't working with `$('.email')` because the class doesn't exist

Comment: I just adapt to what he did. But i add it's a bad idea sending things like email via url and he should just do `url:"/add/newsletter"` then get the email via request

Comment: you are right, sorry. but `$('.email')` doesn't work.

Comment: That's what i thought too. I'm usually working with VueJs so i've got my `v-model` and that's work fine. I don"t really know how that's work without since i always used VueJs. I just assumed he knew what he did since he didn't ask anything about that.

Comment: And I don't know how to pass argument to it, I set url: '/add/newsletter/' and then what should I do ?

Comment: your argument are passed by your `data:$("form").serialize()`, but do you know what you are doing with the `$("form").serialize()` ? I usually works with vueJs so i don't know how it works without but this doesn't seems good to me

Comment: I just want to get email from newsletter form which contains only email. If request will go for /add/newsleter/sample@email.com it will add to newsletter list. I can't use serialize because there is more forms on a page and more values are applied

Comment: @Chrzanek Why dont you pass parameter by `data: {email: email}`?

Comment: @Chrzanek I juste did an edit. check if it's more what you want

Comment: @Chrzanek is that you who upvote the answer ? If it is please tell me if the solution worked

Comment: @SylvainAttoumani kind of. I also changed route to /add/newsletter and add method: GET to it then changed path to Controller instead of hardcode route. Then pass argument like you just wrote.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
public function addToNewsletterAction(Request $request){
  $email = $request->email;
}
```

Or Try:

```
public function addToNewsletterAction($email=''){
  echo $email; //or whatever you want to do with email
}
```

Comment: I've code inside but I don't know how to pass request through the form with ajax

Comment: if he had the parameter email in route you should set the default value in definition of route. not in controller action